# Reloading a Listview Created using LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, listview, android-linearlayout

I am creating a `ListView` using `LinearLayout`. I am doing this because I want to place this list inside a `ScrollView`. Here is how I create the list with `LinearLayout`.

```
adapter = new BookingSessionListAdapter(this,null, appDeleg);  
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.listLayout);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
newLinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)   
{    
    View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);    
    ll.addView(item,layoutParams);

}
```

Now I want to refresh the list. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: listview by itself is scrollable right??

Comment: Don't put list view inside scroll view.
From 42:50:    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me tell you that you are using a real crude implementation to display a `List`. You might wanna consider using `ListView` for this instead of reinventing the wheel. However here's a crude piece of code that will refresh your `List` according to data in a new `BookingSessionListAdapter`.

```
public void refreshList(BookingSessionListAdapter adapter, LinearLayout ll,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams) {
    ll.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
        ll.addView(item, layoutParams);

    }
}
```

What this does is remove all `Views` in your `LinearLayout` and add `Views` according to the new `BookingSessionListAdapter`

Comment: I have to place a listview inside scrollview. So listview is not an option in that case. Thats y i used this.

Comment: I see, but you might run into problems later. Would you mind accepting my answer if you find my solution useful?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do the work by yourself, which comes usually with the ListView for free. It's hard to come up with a solution without knowing anything about your data (how many items, etc.)

One way would be that you remove all views from your LinearLayout and add new views again:

```
protected void notifyDataChange() {
   ll.removeAllViews();
   for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {    
      View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);    
      ll.addView(item,layoutParams);
   }
}
```

However, I would rethink your entire approach, since the ListView / Adapter would do all the heavy work (memory management / caching of views, etc) for you.

HTH.